# Region Plot using Point data

Tags: geometry

so far I use a listplot to create a geometry from a data point. to use the are feature, it requires using the region. anyone know how to make a geometry from point data using region plot?

```
g = {{2, -0.5}, {4, 1}, {4, 3}, {3, 4}, {1, 4}, {-1, 4}, {-1.5, 
    3}, {-1, 2}, {-0.5, 1}, {-0.5, -0.5}, {2, -0.5}};
ListLinePlot[g]
```

[image]

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Please post your point data and some Mathematica code.

Comment: You can ask a new question since this question have been closed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use "Volume" not only with regions, but also wit graphics objects. This can be e.g. done by creating e.g. a 3D object from your points. Here is an example:

We first create some random 3D points:

```
SeedRandom[8];
pts= RandomReal[{-1,1},{4,3}];
```

then we create a polyhedron:

```
poly = Polyhedron[pts, {{2, 3, 4}, {3, 2, 1}, {4, 1, 2}, {1, 4, 3}}]
Graphics3D[poly]
```

(*unfortunately, picture upload is not working*)

Then you can get the volume by:

```
Volume[poly]

(* 0.370183 *)
```

If you insist on using Region, you can transform poly to a region and then use Volume:

```
reg = Region[poly]
Volume[reg]

(* 0.370183 *)
```